# Grant remote Create and Update access to tables in MySQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I'm a new user of MySQL database. In my scenario I installed MySQL in one of my client’s machine which is located in another domain. I could able to connect to his database using his credentials. I can acess show databases and all preliminary things. But when I tried to create and update tables in a database, it is showing an error “Error Code 1142 CREATE command denied to user ‘root’@’computer_name.company.com’”. I used “GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ‘Database_name’.* TO ‘root’@’computer_name.company.com’” and “FLUSH PRIVILEGES”. I also checked all possible MySQL privileges on Firewall. Please let me know where did I go wrong. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

check if there're other users matching'root'@'%.company.com' (select * from mysql.user);
try change your password by adding "IDENTIFIED BY 'xxx'";

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. Yea there is a another user with name 'root'. But my computer name is unique right? I also used "IDENTIFIED BY 'xxx'"; but with no luck.

Comment: "show processlist" to see what's the Host of your connection? or GRANT to IP but not hostname of your computer?

Comment: Hi ZYTU, So you are asking me to use IP of my computer instead of hostname?